# Display the axios response data in frontend

Tags: react-native, axios

I'm trying to display the axios response data in the react native front end.I don't have a clear understand how to do it.

I tried to store the response data into an array and display it as a flat list.But still not getting the out put

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, FlatList} from 'react-native';

const serverURL ='http://192.168.8.100:5000';
const http = axios.create({
   baseURL:serverURL,
});

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      treeType:'',
      midgirth:'',
      length:'',
      rslt:[],
    };
  }


  onCalculate(){
    const{treeType,midgirth,length,rslt} = this.state;

    http.post('/calculations',{
      treeType:treeType,
      midGirth:midgirth,
      length:length
    })
    .then(function(response){
      rslt.push(response.data);
      alert("Response :",response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(rslt);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      alert("Error",error);
    });

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
        style={styles.textinput}
        placeholder="Tree Type"
        onChangeText={(val)=>this.setState({treeType:val})}
        />
        <TextInput style={styles.textinput} 
        placeholder="Mid-Girth"
        underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
        onChangeText={midgirth=> this.setState({midgirth})}
        />
        <TextInput style={styles.textinput} 
        placeholder="Length"
        underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
        onChangeText={length=> this.setState({length})}
        />
        <Button title='Calculate' onPress={()=>this.onCalculate()}/>

        <FlatList
          data={this.state.rslt}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  textinput: {
    backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
    borderRadius:20,
    paddingHorizontal:16,
    color:'#000000',
    fontSize:25,
    marginVertical:10,
    borderWidth:3,
    borderColor: '#005662',
    margin:10,
},
});
```

When the user clicked the button I need to send the post request to backend and display the response data in the front end

Comment: How does the response look like?  What's the output of `console.log(rslt)`/ `console.log(response.data)` ?

Comment: are you sure that your backend sends something back? everything seems relatively fine in your code. you should get at least something if backend responds

Comment: you don't see any alerts, rigth?

Comment: {currentPrice: 3506183.4, length: 2000, midgirth: 1, treetype: "Jak", usefulLogCCM: 3539600, …}   this is the out put i got from console.log(response.data) @TimH

Comment: I am getting the response alert.I want to display all key value pairs in a flatlist. So can i render two items in single flat list?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are mutating the state rather than calling setState which tells react to re-render your component.

You need to do something like this:

```
http.post('/calculations', {
    treeType: treeType,
    midGirth: midgirth,
    length: length
})
.then(function (response) {
    rslt.push(response.data);
    this.setState({rslt}); // or this.forceUpdate();
    alert("Response :", response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(rslt);
}.bind(this))
.catch(function (error) {
    alert("Error", error);
});
```

Comment: This code giving me the error alert. And when I put a console.log(error) I got this error "this.setState is not a function"